# Word form of "lie" in this sentence?

Tags: word-formation

I have this sentence

> The _____ strength of this novel is the author's life experience

And it needs a word form of **lie** to fill in the gap. At first, I think it's **lying** but it sounds weird to me.

Comment: you could use 'lay' - http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/lay-vs-lie

Comment: @JonMarkPerry This is a word formation exercise and I think **lay** is not a great choice

Comment: Why do you think it's a form of lie?  Where did this come from?  Is there context?

Comment: @Xanne I don't know, it's my teacher's exercise and it's the full sentence

Comment: Well, the teacher probably meant for the following to be the answer:  The strength of this novel lies in the author's life experience, but the teacher got the question wrong.

Comment: I would email the teacher and ask him/her to verify if this problem as written is a typo or not. You might want to ask if Xanne's wording was intended to be the correct one. (To show that you are making an effort to use lie/lies correctly.)

Comment: I'm curious about how this turned out.  What was the answer?

Comment: **UNDERLYING** strength

Answer (score 0):

> The UNDERLYING strength of this novel is the author's life experience

Merriam-Webster defines **[underlying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying)** as:  basic, fundamental

> - *an investigation of the underlying issues*

[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/underlying) classifies the expression as C2 (proficiency level)
and says:

> **underlying** <sub>adjective</sub> [ before noun ] (NOT OBVIOUS)
>   real but not immediately obvious:
>
> - On the surface it's a very funny novel but it does have a more serious **underlying** theme.

Comment: This could very well be the intended answer. Just too bad for the teacher that _underlying_ isn't a form of _lie_, making the entire exercise highly misleading and basically impossible to complete as written. 

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet isn't the participle *lying* derived from *lie*? It's one of those transformation, [Use of English](http://www.examenglish.com/FCE/fce_use_of_english_part3.htm), exercises that teachers give to students preparing for B2 and C1 English exams.

Comment: Not quite. _Lying_ is an **inflected** form of _lie_. _Underlie_, conversely, isn't an inflected form of _lie_, but a **derivation** from it. Exercises like this one that put the base form of the verb to use in parentheses usually limit themselves to inflection, not derivation—otherwise it's just too broad for any learner to reasonable find a single, correct answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 99% of the time I find myself in agreement with you, but here the task is to "transform" the term, the candidates know this, and if they have been "trained" they should know that prefixes and suffixes can be added onto words, in this case we have two affixes. The task is a legitimate, and it's also a useful one. It helps learners be aware how manipulative and flexible English is.

Comment: If they've established from the start that derivation may be required, then fine. But in my experience as a student who's gone through exercises like these with many different teachers in many different languages, derivation is usually _not_ involved, only inflection. _Lie_ -> _underlie_ isn't transforming the verb, but creating an entirely different verb from the first. If the exercise is phrased as needing “a form of the verb ___”, then this would fall wide: _underlie_ is not a form of _lie_. Of course, in more advanced levels, there's good reason to have exercises which ->

Comment: -> specifically ask the student to use derivation to find not only a form of the verb, but a form of _an appropriate derived verb_ to fill in; but from the description in the question, this doesn't seem to be such an exercise. Such exercises must also be handled with caution as they very easily become ambiguous or even misleading, e.g., “My sister’s been single for nearly ten years; she's the ___ person I know (happy)”, where the expected answer is ‘unhappiest’; or “This idea is a holdover from ___ notions of chastity (five)”, where the expected answer is ‘fifties’.